# How can I have a concerted addition of bromines?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

I know how to add Bromines in the antiperiplanar position, but I have no idea how to get concerted addition:

[image]

Perhaps I am not seeing something obvious, but I would greatly appreciate any hint.

Comment: As briefly mentioned in the answer, *concerted* does not mean what you think it means. It means that a reaction proceeds in one step, without any intermediates. Examples of concerted reactions are the $\mathrm{S_N2}$ reaction, or the Diels-Alder reaction - see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concerted_reaction).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper term for *concerted addition* is *syn addition*.  I can't find any way of a direct way of producing a syn-addition product.  The only way I can figure you would have to do it is if you did the halogenation with water as the solvent you would get the halo-hydrin product with an anti-addition.  You could then follow this up with a bromination using $\ce{P,Br2}$ or $\ce{PBr3}$ which would invert the chirality and give you a syn-product.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! P is for "products", right?

Comment: I don't how a bromination would work since I don't have a double bond... Sorry. :)

Comment: P is for phosphrous I will update the answer